# Multiple or only one thread that accepts connections?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, winsock

I need some guidance on how to accept connections. I have a server with a thread pool (e.g. 30 threads)

Now I don't know if **(A)** I should take advantage of these existing threads to accept connections, or **(B)** if I should make a single thread that handles this instead.

**B** Unsure of the this method because the program cannot accept connections before it is time for the accepting/single thread to run its tasks.

**A**. This feels better. Using AcceptEx and having multiple threads waiting in GetQueuedCompletionStatus. The first thread that receives the package can then call AcceptEx() again.

Let's say that the server has 1000 connections waiting to be accepted. Which method works best and fastest?

Best regards
Arre

Comment: Overlapped I/O (not just for accepts, but also for reads/writes) is generally  preferred as the best way to handle high traffic load in a scalable manner on Windows. Actually, [Registered I/O](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh997032(v=ws.11)) on Windows 8+ is even more performant, but is too new to be widely used yet.

Comment: Typically you would have a single thread doing accept and setup max allowed connections (which is a lot easier to implement over a single thread). A situation when you have 1000 pending connections is pathological, should never happen. Multiple threads doing accept may perform better but I doubt the difference is noticable. And it may perform (or rather scale) worse, if those threads are supposed to do other things, like handling accepted connections. Anyway I don't think accept is ever a bottleneck. And single-threaded accept is easier to implement, maintain and control.

Comment: @freakish "And it may perform (or rather scale) worse, if those threads are supposed to do other things, like handling accepted connections." - 
I also thought about this then I thought that if I run out of "handling threads" then it doesn't matter if the client has been accepted. The request will still be delayed.

Comment: @Arre well, the client is unable to distinguish "server is busy, can't accept right now" and "server is down" or "there is no server at all (e.g. incorrect tcp destination)". I'd say it is better for UX to always accept and lag on streaming. That way at least you know you've connected.

Comment: @freakish Good thinking. I will allow the threadpool to accept connections, but I will also have a single thread ("a receptionist") who does nothing else but wait for incoming clients to accept. Then the other threads can be there as backup when they are available. Maybe overkill but then I don't have to worry about this anymore

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the tip. will definitely look into it in the future. Too bad you didn't mention it before I started with IOCP. I have changed method so many times now  that I have to stick to IOCP this time.

Comment: @Arre IOCP is fine, even better than plain Overlapped I/O. But I would definitely not use 1 thread to handle all of the accepting. `AcceptEx` can report status to an IOCP, then the handier can kick off `WSARecv` and `WSASend` calls as needed, which can also report status to the IOCP